# Cómo agregar a una grilla sólo entidades nuevas en el CRM Dynamics 2015?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Realicé una sub grilla con una relación 1 a N (1 Contrato, N firmantes). Desde la entidad contrato,en la grilla, quisiera agregar a los firmantes a través del botón +. Pero cuando lo aprieto, por default, se me visualiza un lookup.

En vez del look up, quiero que este botón + me redireccione a un new de la entidad " firmante".

Desde ya , muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El campo **Contrato** en la entidad **Firmante** debe estar como requerido, de esa manera CRM automáticamente abre un nuevo registro desde un subgrid y no el asociar existente.